# Can we calculate absolute value function in homomorphic encryption efficiently？

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

Is it feasible to efficiently calculate a homomorphic absolute value function over ciphertext given a pair of numbers $a$ and $b$, i.e., |a-b|? Although there are approximate methods that use addition and multiplication, their runtime in my project is intolerable. Is there any homomorphic absolute value function that is faster than homomorphic multiplication? And what if $a$ and $b$ are real-value vectors?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography. Your question is not clear to me. Are you asking $FHE\_ABS(x)$ function that calculates the absolute value of an encrypted value? Could you provide links to existing ones?

Comment: You can [edit] your question to clarify.